# Minimal CMS for Reactive Web App Articles

Tags: cms

I am constructing a social reactive web app. Most of the content is dynamically user-generated but the app will also have ‘static articles’.
These articles will be created internally by an author. This content will be VERY simple and may contain text, images, headers (no styling or javascript). I essentially would like my app to query available articles, process/style, and serve it through my app view.

Things I need
* Intuitive editor for author
* Rest API for my app to request articles
* Open source or free trial
* Basic versioning support
* Metadata support
* Minimal (if possible)

Comment: Take a look at http://www.cmsmatrix.org/